# JPA vs JavaBeans validation (JSR 303) vs your solution: Automatically truncate field before persisting

Tags: java, database, jpa, bean-validation

I have some fields in the database that have a fixed length. I'm fairly new to `JPA` and `JSR 303`.

JPA won't let me persist an entity that has a field with a greater size than is allowed in the db (which is what I want); and describing `@Column`s with a `length` parameter is only useful for ddl generation.

Also, AFAIK, describing parameters with JSR 303's `@Size` will only trigger an answer when I want the field to be modified.

I was wondering what was the standard way of handling that truncation, using JSR 303, JPA, or something else.

EDIT: Is it possible to enable some auto-truncation in JPA?

Best regards

Comment: Depending on the database you're using, you might just be able to have it automatically truncate long fields.

Comment: The setter of your field in the entity could simply truncate the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The database is Oracle 10g, but I'm not looking for the DB way to do it. Plus my DBA is grumpy.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, this seems the right way to do it. Though, is it possible to make JPA auto-truncate the fields that are too lengthy? I'm looking for the lazy/maintainable way, there is about 600 fields.

Comment: Frankly, automatically truncating data is not something I would do, and certainly not "automatically" or "by default". If I want to store something in the database and it doesn't fit, I prefer being warned about it by an exception rather than having it truncated (i.e. made incorrect) and saved blindly, without notice. That will make things much worse later.

Comment: How to handle invalid input data isn't really a concern that should be handled at the ORM layer.

Answer (score 1):

Like JB Nizet suggested it can be done with setter. But that won't make it a strict Java Bean.

You could also implement it in database but that will make your implementation less portable.

The best way would be to keep this logic outside the bean or DB. I.e. in your application logic.

**Update:**

If you need to do truncation in JPA have a look at @EntityListeners and callbacks.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: Yes, I do agree. I should put it within some kind of data formatting class. However, I wanted to avoid putting description of the Entity fields far away. Do you know of a good pattern to do it?